# Swift - Use GTMAppAuth to authorize google calendar api?

Tags: swift, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I haven´t found a library to use with swift to implement the GoogleCalendarAPI calls, so I decided to do it by myself parsing the JSON response with my app model!

The problem is that I can´t find a way to use the GTMAppAuth to grant access to my app to the CalendarAPI! I couldn´t find any Swift libraries (except for the old ones that are deprecated) and I don´t know what else to do.

*Has anyone retrieved events from GoogleCalendarAPI with Swift?

*Do I need to use the GoogleSignIn (which contains the GTMAppAuth) and the GoogleAPIClientForREST (that is supposed to have the calendar API inside)?

I have already logged in the user using FirebaseAuth and GoogleSignInApi.

I expect to show the user calendar events into a table view in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GTMAppAuth library and [follow the documentation](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth#making-api-calls) to authenticate an user and make API calls.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ZektorH First Of all, thanks for your answer. My problem is that I don't know much about Obj-c so I'm stuck trying to understand the calls to the GTMAppAuth. I just can´t understand how to implement it, maybe it´s time for me to learn some Obj-c hahaha.

Comment: @DairaBezzato could you please update your question with the code you currently have and any errors you are getting?

Comment: I am finishing the swift way to call the API. If you want when I have at least one call I update the question with the code. I have just realized that I can translate Obj-c code to swift. It will take a little time but I´m on it :D